# sencha touch local storage insert ID

Tags: html, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, local-storage

I have a small problem if you can help me it would be great. I cant insert my own ID to the local storage.

```
ext.define('EMC.model.ReferenceData', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        identifier: {
            type: 'simple'
        },

        idProperty: 'Id',

        fields: [
                 {name: 'Id', type: 'string'},
                 {name: 'Description', type: 'string'},
                 {name: 'syncChangeVersion', type: 'integer', mapping: 'SysChangeVersion'},
                 {name: 'TypeEnum', type: 'string'}         
        ]     


    }
});
```

this is a model of my project and the store is shown below.

```
Ext.define("EMC.store.SyncReferenceData", {
    extend : "Ext.data.Store",
    requires : [ 'Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage' ],

    config : {
        model : 'EMC.model.ReferenceData',
        storeId : 'referenceStore',
        sorters : 'Id',


        proxy : {
            type : 'localstorage',
            id : 'reference_data'
        },

        autoSync : true,
        autoLoad : true


    }
});
```

this is the phrase I created to insert data to the local storage using controller.

```
var frmModel2 = Ext.create('EMC.model.ReferenceData',{
    Id : '13',
    Description : 'lole',
    syncChangeVersion : 0,
    TypeEnum  : '199'
    });
    ReferenceStore.add(frmModel2); 
    ReferenceStore.sync();
```

But when I see the local storage it is empty. But If i comment Id : '13' then it will add to the local storage with a id of "ext-record-293".
why cant I inset my own Id to the store?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
   Ext.define('EMC.model.ReferenceData', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

        config: {
            dProperty : 'uniqueid', // dummy name(not a field)
            clientIdProperty : 'Id',

            fields: [
                {name: 'Id', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'Description', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'syncChangeVersion', type: 'integer', mapping: 'SysChangeVersion'},
                {name: 'TypeEnum', type: 'string'}         
            ]            

        }
    });
```